# Convert SKSurface to SKBitmap and resize into a image of a specific size on different device sizes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have a Xamarin forms view where based on touch events i can alter the image

```
 <StackLayout > 
        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                           PaintSurface="ImageCanvas_PaintSurface"  
                           EnableTouchEvents="True" 
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           IgnorePixelScaling="True"// not sure if i need this??
                           Touch="OnTouch" />
        <Button Text="Generate Image" Clicked="CreateButton_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

I need to generate a image of exactly 1060 x 550 based on what is drawn on the surface

```
 void ImageCanvas_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
     {
            var surface = args.Surface;
            var canvas = surface.Canvas;

        /// paint bitmaps/text on canvas etc 


        // Save the image to local storage
        ViewModel.SaveImage(surface.Snapshot()); 
     }
```

As far i can see If i could convert the SKImage which is returned from the surface.Snapshot() into a SKBitmap, I could use the Resize() function. How do i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach sounds OK to me. You need to consider that screen sizes on different devices will not match the 1060x550, so you will either need to crop or stretch the image to fill the entire 1060x550 image. Why is it that you need this specific 1060x550 resolution?

Comment: my requirement requires this exact size so i have no choice sadly. Still not sure how to convert a SKImage into a SKBitmap however? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take picture and save it as SKImage in device folder after that you get it as stream and resize it and re-save it again

```
        SKImage snapI = e.Surface.Snapshot();
        SKData pngImage = snapI.Encode();
        var x=  Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "FolderName");
        var fullpath = x+"PicName.png";
        File.WriteAllBytes(fullpath, pngImage.ToArray());
        SKBitmap bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(fullpath);
        var dstInfo = new SKImageInfo(1060, 550);

        bitmap.Resize(dstInfo, SKBitmapResizeMethod.Hamming);
```

You can ameliorate and optimize the code more as your needs.