# Skia - crop SKSurface to content

Tags: c#, skia, skiasharp

I'm new to Skia.
I need to crop the dimension of an SKSurface to its non white/transparent content.

Do I have to iterate all the pixels? Are there better and/or faster alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846848/convert-sksurface-to-skbitmap-and-resize-into-a-image-of-a-specific-size-on-diff

Comment: @Fuzzybear thanks but no, if I understand well he is resizing it, I need to crop. I changed the tile of the question accordingly

Comment: ah so u need to crop as well... hmm yeh not sure then sorry can not help more